# PC freezes completely with Linux after a few minutes (dual boot), windows works normally

Tags: linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot, freeze

**OS:** Fedora-windows 10 (first time) ; Ubuntu-windows 10 (second time)

**Hardware:** GTX 760 2GB ; i5 4690 ; 8GB ram ; Gigabyte B85M-D3PH(motherboard)

**Explanation:** I am a beginner to Linux, and decided to try dual booting windows and linux for the first time, choosing Fedora as my distro. However, after the installation, my PC would randomly freeze when trying to configure my audio settings, without any response at (nothing works). It kept happening every single time when I used fedora(it would work for some minutes and then freeze), while windows works apparently fine and I haven't gotten any freezes on it.
Since I couldn't find any useful info online on how to fix it, I decided to remove Fedora and install Ubuntu instead.
Now with Ubuntu, it still keeps freezing completely, and after a few seconds with the system frozen, my PC just turns off and I can't figure out why it only happens with Linux, and not when I choose windows from the dual boot.
Another problem I had was inside GRUB. When I choose "Ubuntu", the screen gets completely black, and after waiting for quite a while, nothing happens. The only way to make Ubuntu boot at all is going to the advanced options, and choosing (the kernel version?idk).
Also, Ubuntu and Fedora were being kind of slow, which is weird, since I've used linux on other computers and it feels way smoother on them, whereas on mine it feels terrible to use

**ERROR:** the image contains the error message I was receiving when trying to boot Ubuntu directly from "Ubuntu" on GRUB, without going to advanced settings:
[image: ubuntu_error]

**Question:** What could possibly be causing my computer to freeze completely with Linux every time?
-Why couldn't I boot Ubuntu normally on GRUB and what did that message mean?
-Why was Linux being so slow on my computer, even though my PC settings aren't that bad?

Comment: It is hard to answer this one because it is multiple questions in one. As for the error with Ubuntu: It is a [known problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417618/mtd-device-must-be-supplied-device-name-is-empty) which will probably be resolved soon. The crashes are harder to explain. In your case I guess it is a problem with the graphics card drivers. When you select one of the alternative startup options in GRUB, you might select a "safe mode" configuration. The maximum compatibility drivers (e.g. VESA) offer no hardware acceleration. The system boots, but it feels slow.